# Flutter 3.7.12 not work and cause this Error: Unable to find git in your PATH

Tags: flutter, git, dart

Whenever I run the flutter or dart commands on the VS code Terminal I get "Error: Unable to find Git in your PATH".

I've already tried to the solutions from other suggestions like making sure the PATH contains:

C:\Windows\System32
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
C:\Program Files\Git\bin and/or C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe
C:\Program Files\Git\cmd
C:\src\flutter\bin

this problem after installing the Flutter 3.7.12 version.
flutter commands work in cmd but not work in VS code Terminal.
I reinstalled Git and tried it on the command line and Git works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have installed git through other mediums other than what is said by vs code docs, you need to configure the git path in the environment of vs code.

To do so, go to *File* > *Preferences* > *Settings*.

This will open a JSON like file.

Add these lines to the file:

```
{
   "git.path": "C:\\users\\username\\path\\to\\git\\excutable",
   "git.enabled": true,
}
```

Also, remember to restart your vscode instance.

Comment: i did it but still same error Error: Unable to find git in your PATH.  @Just a Person

Comment: @MalihaArash I would then recommend you to try uninstalling git and then reinstall it.

Answer (score 0):

run this cmd will solve issue

git config --global --add safe.directory '*'